# Download UI contents from a URL in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

I am building a flutter app that will contain a lot of animated pictures and 3d objects. Many of those animations will be choosen based on the user choice of gender when registering for the first time. So one of the issues with flutter is that it normally takes a lot of storage and with this animations its gonna need even more storage. So I was wondering if there is a way to keep those animations online in some cloud or in firestore DB and then when the user register for the first time I download it and assign it to the UI to be permenantly there instead of like storing all these Gifs in the assets.
Any suggestiong to avoid storing all of the animations and images in the assets.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you have lots of images, I would suggest you use a dedicated server to store your images.
If you haven't any dedicated server, then you should use firebase to store your images.

You should follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70336035/17956869) to fetch images from firebase.
Also, you should follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66555837/17956869) to store your images in the cache & in the future fetch from the cache easily.